# Typescript conditional return type based on props

Tags: reactjs, typescript, electron

1. In electron application I have a component that renders a button and sends a message to an arbitrary channel to the `main` process.
2. The `main` process does some work and returns back the result, its return type is depended on the channel name.
3. Parent component also passes a callback along with channel name.

```
const Button = ({ name, channel, callback }: ButtonProps) => {
  const [isDisabled, setDisabled] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const onClickHandler = () => {
    setDisabled(true);
    window.electron.ipcRenderer.sendMessage(channel);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    // type definition for the function below:
    // on<T>(channel: string, func: (result: T) => void): () => void;
    window.electron.ipcRenderer.on<ReturnType>(channel, (result) => {
      setDisabled(false);
      callback(result);
    });

    return () => {
      window.electron.ipcRenderer.removeAllListeners(channel);
    };
  }, [channel, callback]);

  return <button 
           type="button" 
           onClick={onClickHandler} 
           disabled={isDisabled}
         >
           {name}
         </button>;
};

export default Button;
```

How do I specify a type of a `result` that is being passed to a callback?

I started with something like this:

```
type ReturnType = OpenDialogReturnValue | SaveDialogReturnValue;

type ButtonProps = {
  name: string;
} & (
  | {
      channel: "OPEN_DIALOG";
      callback: (result: OpenDialogReturnValue) => void;
    }
  | {
      channel: "SAVE_EXAMPLE";
      callback: (result: SaveDialogReturnValue) => void;
    }
);
```

But it throws type error on the line with `callback(result)`;

```
Argument of type 'ReturnType' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OpenDialogReturnValue & SaveDialogReturnValue'.
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: Avoid naming a type `ReturnType`: it shadows the TypeScript utility type https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype

Comment: Hi, if my answer helped resolve your question, would you mind accepting it? Thankyou!

Comment: @OvidijusParsiunas I'm allowing couple more weeks for other opinions to come through, if nothing changes I'll gladly accept your answer, appreciate your time writing it, I keep an eye on this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways you can tackle this issue.

**The core problem**

The reason why you are seeing that error is because even though you had separated the differentiating values for `channel` and `callback` properties into two respectively different objects, `channel` and `callback` types are still undetermined when they are within the `useEffect` function. This means that TypeScript does not know what parameter type the `callback` should have and will automatically request an intersection of both
`OpenDialogReturnValue` and `SaveDialogReturnValue` types just to be sure that whatever the callback is in runtime - it will definitely get an object argument that it can use.

**Solutions**

1. The simplest way to fix this is to lend TypeScript a hand and tell it to trust us by using type casting. As we already know, TypeScript is asking us to provide an argument for `callback` with an intersection type as it is not sure which `callback` function will exist in runtime `((result: OpenDialogReturnValue) => void) | (result: SaveDialogReturnValue) => void))`. We can instead tell TypeScript that there is only one `callback` and it is the argument types that vary `(results: OpenDialogReturnValue | SaveDialogReturnValue) => void`. This can be done by first extracting the possible parameter types that `callback` can have by using a Utility type called `Parameters` and then casting its first parameter over `callback` to assign a new variable called `typedCallback`:

```
useEffect(() => {
  type CallbackParameterTypes = Parameters<typeof callback>;
  const typedCallback = callback as (results: CallbackParameterTypes[0]) => void;
  window.electron.ipcRenderer.on<CallbackParameterTypes[0]>(channel, (result) => {
    setDisabled(false);
    typedCallback(result);
  });
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAgPAFQHwAoIAsCGYYApgDYBciAzlAE4xgDmANIqJJVrcVSKVJTQBKRAF4MiAG5wYAEyGVpcxAG8AvgFgAUNoZRitYPgjFEAeQAOxMABEY%20UnEYAlYlBC0wANQchTK7UREfFpGAEZKGnomAG5tTR0tPQMjE0QAZXxJYjsHJ1d3Tx9SP1VA4NCAJki6BkY4rQTtKABPK0QAIRAoKAQABVo4CyoxMq0gsHwAW2Ia6Pr4xAAyRCxygB8xoO3EPEISCkQAIjM%20gFEAOQB9GwBJAEEAGTMAcSOGnaCIB1IAI2MANacbi8fiUSzWXKOFxuDzeXzEETiKQyWQfbYJIKbALjT57IhkShHdL3LxnK5nAAa9wAsn1Hmd3uUdt9SH9AcCeHwBBksjl7NCCnDin4kRIlGjmYgEkIGtoAPTyxBCzxoNqmVrtSYzRAwEb4RAggzZWSIbXEVi4axpW7BCxWMCyYimg2VZrq5Ww1XqyqjCG2AX5L3wkqmTaZbJQoOFEN%20OVadjQeBIKYtABi4CTCCwFkGw0oXR6-TzVAUKOUOK%20CBoqjN0wtuwIBNIrFZ7IgAOlo1zQyo6M1pgAwj9-h2%20iF6-paGqrCNRIhx7RJwYqCgB3BgLsR4CMOUINWoIgB7Jh2zR53523z8ERlwufwqJRT%202AYvl9P1VQANoABgAumK5aSriqDPueb4zFOM48L%20f7YPiBysHeoJQIBlbbMeYGAsh3KyuUah4Y02hAA).

2. If the association between `channel` and `callback` parameter types do not matter, then the above can be simplified into the following:

```
type ButtonProps = {
  name: string;
  channel: "OPEN_DIALOG" | "SAVE_EXAMPLE";
  callback: (result: OpenDialogReturnValue | SaveDialogReturnValue) => void;
};
```

```
useEffect(() => {
  window.electron.ipcRenderer.on<Parameters<typeof callback>[0]>(channel, (result) => {
    setDisabled(false);
    callback(result);
  });
```

[Playground Link.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAgPAFQHwAoIAsCGYYApgDYBciAzlAE4xgDmANIqJJVrcVSKVJTQBKRAF4MiAG5wYAEyGVpcxAG8AvgFgAUNoZRitYPgjFEAeQAOxMABEY%20UnEYAlYlBC0wANQchTK7UREfFpGAEZKGnomAG5tTR0tPQMjE0QAZXxJYjsHJ1d3Tx9SP1VA4NCAJki6BkY4rQTtAHpmxAKPMDQATytEKF7TMHwAW1MYKmDEbioDbNlEYbHWXGs0gElgiyswWWIF-ERK7QG%20js8eq0qxcx3cxxc3TuLSgB8MrJz7B-PvX2IGidBogAEIgKBQBAABVocAsk1EZS0QSWxBq0Xq5TwhBIFEQACIzFCAKIAOQA%20jZ1gBBAAyZgA4vjEO98elqV5ieTiQANakAWShtOJ%20IaQQgDlIACNjABrTgzPgCW7We75J5Ff4sj7ZNWPQp-ErEETiKQyWQNNSArTsaDwJAjboAMXAdoQWAssPhlDBEOhXqoCjNygCyMQEAQNFUi1GxFY2KIZHjkplEFliDUN09cKoYuQYBQUJCsf0tCoKFOxDgwHDKblGAA2gAGAC62ATuNYXB4SpNElDQXFdbT3d4-CEebUE-i2iAA)

3. Another way you can approach the problem is by using type predicates which can be difficult to maintain, however they let TypeScript know exactly what type is being used when. To apply them, you would first need to refactor the union objects into separate interfaces; e.g. `OpenDialogObject` and `SaveExampleObject`. You can then use an `is` type predicate to tell TypeScript which particular interface does the current `props` object adhere to as done in the `isOpenDialog` function. The function itself uses the `channel` property to decide which type the object is. This can then be used within `useEffect` to help determine what parameter type `props.callback` is going to have during runtime. However as you can observe - the syntax can get a little bit repetitive, especially if you will have more types. For completeness; the type predicate function will only produce wanted results when passing and inferring the full `props` object and not individual `channel` and `callback` properties. The reason for that is because these property types are not enough to determine what type the overall object will be:

```
interface OpenDialogObject {
  channel: "OPEN_DIALOG";
  callback: (result: OpenDialogReturnValue) => void;
}

interface SaveExampleObject {
  channel: "SAVE_EXAMPLE";
  callback: (result: SaveDialogReturnValue) => void;
}

type ButtonProps = {name: string;} & (OpenDialogObject | SaveExampleObject);
```

```
if (isOpenDialog(props)) {
  window.electron.ipcRenderer.on<Parameters<typeof callback>[0]>(channel, (result) => {
    setDisabled(false);
    callback(result);
  });
} else {
  window.electron.ipcRenderer.on<Parameters<typeof callback>[0]>(channel, (result) => {
    setDisabled(false);
    callback(result);
  });
}
```

[Playground Link.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=39&ssc=4&pln=31&pc=3#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAgPAFQHwAoIAsCGYYApgDYBciAzlAE4xgDmANIqJJVrcVSKVJTQBKRAF4MiAG5wYAEyGVpcxAG8AvgFgAUNoZRitYPgjFEAeQAOxMABEY%20UnEYAlYlBC0wANQchTK7UREfFpGAEZKGnomAG5tTR0tPQMjE0QAZXxJYjsHJ1d3Tx9SP1VA4NCAJki6BkY4rQTtAHpmxAKPMDQATytEKF7TMHwAW1MYKmDEbioDbNlEYbHWXGs0gElgiyswWWIF-ERK7QG%20js8eq0qxcx3cxxc3TuLSgB8MrJz7B-PvX2IGrowPpDMZTJZrPcnGYAEYAK2I0DKWiCeEIJAoiAARGYAAoAUQAcgB9GzrACCABkzABxLENVEOUgw4wAa04Mz4AlukO%20%20SeRX%20InEUhksgaTSSwJSYI%202XxAA9RhZSMRYQikQEUYg0UQyJQselyV58cT8QANckAWVxlPx9PKECZLIg7MQXB4XMomWyUMehT%20JWIwokSnF8W0J0GiAAQiAoFAELjaHALJNRKolsQatF6mpEAAyd0Q2x8xjqxFQRDvH3ERXK1UV6BCQFadjQeBICYlv1YCwptOUHtlptVmufesjFVq%20GVhSIfupyYTHmlvLl2ea8rcAMLgdUAB0uoxYlEGZxBJJZKptIdjUjbfAHYQiBG3QAYk-YAg%20-vKHGEyTfd5zDZEghgYB3W7O4y1-JchBELUgiCVBcRCUY3AMKgUFOYg4Egxc0yPZ02QwABtAAGABdbBCMPY8yFYD1eH4EMwOQoI6OI0hmTZZiuRbcogjUQTtXzMhZnYlCwBQNDaAwkFsNw-C9yXbjeNdcjqNo-cjwIPVSCYzlWLECQkI41SiKdHiXVZfjWIZZCRMchI1CAA)

Comment: Thanks for this reply. The association between the `channel` and `callback` parameter types is paramount, as you have mentioned it in the 3rd solution. The solution though feels a little bit redundant. What if the component would end up accepting 10 different types of channels, I'd need to maintain 10 different conditions, wouldn't I?

Comment: Hey, I have revisited the answer to be a bit more clear about the problem. In regards to your question, the third solution is indeed the nastiest one, hence I would recommend using the first one as it is type agnostic and is best for the example that you have provided. However, if you will be implementing new logic that will do different kind of processing depending on which channel is being used, then type predicates will be the only way to facilitate it.